# Running python commands in a post-build event on MSBuild

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build-automation

I'm using the command "python setup.py py2exe" in the post build event, when I did a build on VS2008 there's no problem, but when I run my automate build I get the message "Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Post-Build Event..." and "python is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file".

The python path is already declarated at environment variables, the command runs normally if I use on the command prompt manually.

Why MSBuild can't get the right path to execute the python command?

Comment: How about just putting the path to Python in the command?

Comment: Something like `C:\Python2X\python.exe setup.py py2exe`.

Comment: I need anything more generic than that, using the path directly to python.exe is the last option, but thanks anyway

Comment: Marcelo - generic as in using a relative path to your Python executable?